# Avoid infinity in logistical squashing function

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I'm implementing part of a logistic regression function but can't seem to get anything other than -inf. Not sure how you can get anything else since if there is a 1 output, then the log(1-1) turns it into -inf.

Any thoughts?

```
% Calculates error based on X, Y, theta
function error = empRisk(X,Y, theta)
    n = length(X);
    error = 0;
    for i=1: n
        y = Y(i,:);
        x = X(i,:);
        binLoss = classify(theta,x);

        part1 = y-1;
        part2 = log(1-binLoss);% -Inf if 1-1??
        part3 = y*(log(binLoss));

        error = error + ((part1*part2)-part3);
    end

    error = error*(1/n);
end

% Implements the classification function
function value = classify(theta, x)
    z = dot(theta,x);

    result = (1/(1+exp(-z)));

    % Output 0,1 based on result
    if result >= 0.5
        value = 1;
    else
        value = 0;
    end
end
```

Here is the formula empRisk is supposed to be doing: [image]

Comment: This sounds more like an algorithm problem than a programming problem. Is your classification function correct? Maybe `binLoss` should be the `result` variable? Can you give a link to a description of the algorithm you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a bit of a conceptual problem.  [The loss function typically used when talking about empirical risk minimization is the 0-1 loss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_risk_minimization), which is basically 0 when your classified value is equal to your target value and 1 otherwise (and you average this over your training samples.)

If you're talking about [the logistic loss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#As_a_generalized_linear_model), then that's a totally different thing.  In that case, you wouldn't want that final `if` statement in your `classify()` function.  So you should return `result`.

The empirical risk loss (0-1 loss) is non-convex in `theta` and the logistic loss is convex in `theta`, which is one of the reasons that people use it, because it's computationally feasible to find the right `theta` even in large problems.  This isn't the case for the empirical risk loss.